# Export data from a CCURE 800/8000 System using a pair of ODBC data sources?

Tags: odbc, csv, progress-database

I'm working on a security system called CCURE 800/8000 and trying to export some entrance / exit data from the Activity Monitor that logs when people use their badges to enter and exit the building.  There are two ODBC DSNs listed on the machine that controls this...We'll call them DSNNAME and DSNNAME_TXT.

The DSNNAME uses a `Progress OpenEdge 10.2A Driver` and the DSNNAME_TXT uses a `Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt, *.csv)`

## DSNNAME

The description on the `DSNNAME` DSN reads `CCURE Journal Export DSN`, so I am thinking that this connects to the CCURE 800/8000 progress database to pull the information out.  It appears to work, as clicking the `Test Connect` button and entering the username and password result in a `Connection Established!` dialog box.

## DSNNAME_TXT

The description on this DSN reads `CCURE Journal Export DSN for Time & Attendance` I think that this DSN is there to write the exported data to a couple of csv files.

The `DNSNAME_TXT driver` points to a directory in which there is a single file: `Schema.ini`
This file contains the following contents:

```
[timeok.txt]
ColNameHeader=False
Format=Delimited(;)
MaxScanRows=0
CharacterSet=OEM
Col1=ID Char Width 255
Col2=NAME Char Width 255
Col3=DATEIN Char Width 255
Col4=DATEOUT Char Width 255
Col5=HHDIFF Float
Col6=READERIN Char Width 255
Col7=RNAMEIN Char Width 255
Col8=READEROUT Char Width 255
Col9=RNAMEOUT Char Width 255
Col10=FLAG Integer
[timeerr.txt]
ColNameHeader=False
Format=Delimited(;)
MaxScanRows=0
CharacterSet=OEM
Col1=ID Char Width 255
Col2=NAME Char Width 255
Col3=ERRDATEIN Char Width 255
Col4=ERRDATEOUT Char Width 255
Col5=ERRHH Float
Col6=ERRIN Char Width 255
Col7=ERRNAMEIN Char Width 255
Col8=ERROUT Char Width 255
Col9=ERRNAMEOUT Char Width 255
Col10=ERRDESCR Char Width 255

[schema.ini]
ColNameHeader=False
Format=CSVDelimited
MaxScanRows=0
CharacterSet=OEM
```

The file mentions `timeok.txt` and `timeerr.txt` which don't appear anywhere on the machine (I searched the entire hdd), but according to [this documentation](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/149090) they should be in the same directory with `schema.ini` when using the `Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt, *.csv)`.   In further detail about the DSN, the `options >>` button reveals that it's `Extensions List` is selecting `*.*`.

## CCURE 800/800 Administration Client

Inside the `Administration Client` I'm trying to export a report; as I stated above, I believe that the report was meant to be exported into two files `timeok.txt` and `timeerr.txt`

To generate the report in the `Administration Client`:
1. from the menu I click `Reports -> Personnel -> Time and Attendance...`
1. I select a report called `Access` from the `Select Report` list.
1. I click the `Run Report` button
1. I select a `Journal export database` by double clicking that textbox
1. There's one called `Cards` which if I `edit` it, I can see that the `ODBC` tab has `DSNNAME_TXT` set as it's `DSN` (and that clicking the `Test ODBC connection to the Database` with the correct username and password) says that the connection was successful.
1. When I click the `Progress` tab, enter the username and password and click the `Test Progress connection to Database` I also get a message that it succeeded.
1. On the `SQL` tab I check off to enable logging, and the documentation states that a log file is generated in `C:\CCURE800\4gl\Database\Log\DriverErr0.000001.log` which appears to be the case....
1. Lastly I click the `Setup` tab and click `Export Personnel data...` or `Export Object data...` I get a message that reads `Successfully completed Journal Export` message but there is no output in either of the files (`timeok.txt` or `timeerr.txt`) as I would have expected to be the case in doing so....
1. If I actually try to run the report, I end up with an error about a missing `.ocx` file:

```
---------------------------
Error
---------------------------
Specified ActiveX control is not registered or the .ocx file was moved from where it was registered.
Error occurred in procedure: control_load source\rep_sho_excel.w (6087)
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

...followed by another dialog that reads:

```
---------------------------
Error
---------------------------
Microsoft Excel OCX control cannot be loaded. Some components are missing or not registered. (CC-2334)
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

(and again no output...though I did use `procmon` to see what the process was writing out...it looks like it's just a bunch of binary files with no extension (DBI2612a05112) and also a file called `cf.lg`

The error log `C:\CCURE800\4gl\Database\Log\DriverErr0.000001.log` yields some results, but no errors... like this:

```
[14/07/01@05:09:46.655-0400] P-001972 T-001976 1 4GL -- Log entry types activated: 4GLMessages
[14/07/10@05:01:34.542-0400] P-001972 T-001976 1 4GL -- Database CF was disconnected. (1015)
[14/07/10@05:02:55.627-0400] P-001148 T-001168 1 4GL -- Logging level set to = 2
[14/07/10@05:02:55.642-0400] P-001148 T-001168 1 4GL -- Log entry types activated: 4GLMessages
```

I've even tried to connect to the DSNNAME Progress ODBC driver using Squirrel SQL but it states that the connection is not open.  So needless to say I'm pretty stumped at this point; does anyone have experience with any of these old systems to offer some insight into querying this system?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on my experience with ccure 800 in particular, you do need to have MS Excel and all of the supporting MS Office components installed on the same PC as the ccure Administration client. The OCX libraries are required to support the export function.

Comment: Yeah I sort figured that was the case...they should list it as a dependency...but nevermind we're not using Linux here....

Answer (score 3):

OCX files are part of the ActiveX control. There's something wrong with the application and you need to call the vendor to get it fixed.

Comment: Maybe I just need to install Office?  Do you think there's something wrong with the DSNNAME_TXT?

Comment: Looked up the error and found this: http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/19859

Answer (score 3):

In the cCURE 800 Install guide there is a requsite set of software and patches for the OS that need be installed. Including Office XP Web Components and Some patches ( Listed Below) "for Journal Replay and other reports to work"

1. install =Microsoft Office XP Web Components= - 
   [NOTE : f you have office 2003, Access 2003, or Frontpage 2003 installed on your computer then Office XP Web Components are already installed.]
2. KB956464
3. KB2288608
4. KB947320

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the details out, apparently there's an easier way to do it... `Reports-> Journal -> Journal Replay` doesn't get you in the database but it does export the times into a text file.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you may have installation issues with ActiveX. To make sure, however, try and find the missing OCX and register it manually. It could be that the registry is having an issue dealing with the file.

[We have a KB article that directs you how to register](http://ow.ly/z3HfY), and if it turns out the steps in the [article you found](http://ow.ly/z3Hky) don't lead to a resolution, the problem is much more likely to be an incomplete/somehow corrupt installation of ActiveX or an unlisted Office Suite dependancy with CCURE rather than an OE/registry problem.

Best of luck!

Answer (score -1):

This information is readily available from the CCure 800 Administration Client. Not from the monitoring client, therefore i would question your reasons for attempting to get the data this way.